# Custom InfoWindowAdapter has no background

Tags: android, google-maps

I have a strange problem 
i design a app what can user make see some point on Google map ver 2

and i've used InfoWindowAdapter like this :

```
public class PopupAdapter implements  InfoWindowAdapter {
LayoutInflater inflater=null;
View view;
public PopupAdapter(LayoutInflater inflater) {
this.inflater=inflater;
view = this.inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_info_window,null);
}

@Override
public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
return null;
}

@Override
public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
final String title = marker.getTitle();
final TextView titleUi = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title));
if (title != null) {
titleUi.setText(title);
} 
else {
titleUi.setText("");
}
final String snippet = marker.getSnippet();
final TextView snippetUi = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.snippet));
if (snippet != null) {
    snippetUi.setText(snippet);
}else {
     snippetUi.setText("");
} 
 return view;
}
```

and this is my Layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="12dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/snippet"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="10dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>

 </LinearLayout>
```

but when i get popup on my marker it is not have any background and it shows on map just a simple text with no popup frame

i tried to solve this problem but it seems something unusual 
can any one please Help me ???
thank you so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but when i get popup on my marker it is not have any background and it shows on map just a simple text with no popup frame

That's what you asked it to do, by overriding `getInfoWindow()`. If you want the standard info window frame, override `getInfoContents()` instead. Or, include your own frame as part of the `View` you return from `getInfoWindow()`.

Comment: look at these links :
http://android-er.blogspot.com/2013/01/custom-infowindowadapter-with-dynamic.html
http://androidfreakers.blogspot.com/2013/08/display-custom-info-window-with.html

they use simple layout ....

Comment: @PouyaSamie: The first one overrides `getInfoContents()`, not `getInfoWindow()`. The second one supplies a frame background (`@drawable/custom_info_bubble`) as part of the `View` that is returned from `getInfoWindow()`. These are the two solutions that I listed in my answer.